# Fourier transform problem

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms, dirac-delta

I have to show that the Fourier transform of the function $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is:

$$\mathfrak{F}[\ln(x)](k) = \frac{1}{k}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} - \frac{1}{|k|}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}} + i\ \sqrt{\frac{\pi^3}{2}} \delta(k) - \gamma\sqrt{2\pi}\ \delta(k)$$

Where $\gamma = $ Euler-Mascheroni constant and $\delta(k)$ = Dirac Delta function.

Any hint for the integration?

Comment: First, maybe $\log|x|$ to avoid trouble at $x\le 0$? And, then, while $\log|x|$ is a perfectly fine tempered distribution (being locally integrable), it is nowhere close to being in $L^1$, so the literal integral for Fourier transform will have some convergence problems. In how sophisticated a context do you want to do this?

Comment: No, I'm searching for $\ln(x)$, no abs. Also because the F.T. of $\ln(|x|)$ would be a different thing. I need to prove this, that's it..

Comment: Ok, then which $\log x$ do you want for $x<0$? That's not a big deal, but would obviously affect constants in the outcome. So it'd suffice, and be less noisy, to take $f(x)=\log x$ for $x>0$ and just $0$ for $x<0$, and express your original in terms of this. Still, in what context?